# CodeIgniter - Page variables undefined in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a bit baffled. I'm also pretty sure this was working before, but…

This is a pretty basic scenario. Page variables defined in the controller via $data, however for some reason they're not available in the view. Unless I'm going blind I can't see anything wrong with the code.

Controller function (in full for ultimate clarity):

```
function login()
{
    $data['page_title'] = 'Login title';
    $data['page_description'] = 'Login description';
    $data['page_keywords'] = 'login,keywords';
    $data['referer'] = $this->session->flashdata('referer');

    if($this->input->post('email',true) !== false)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_password');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // Log failed attempt against IP address
            $this->bruteforce->log_fail( $this->input->ip_address() , $this->input->post('email',true) );
        }
        else
        {
            // Go to accounts home
            if($this->input->post('referer') != '')
            {
                redirect($this->input->post('referer'));
            }
            else
            {
                redirect('dashboard');
            }

        }
    }

    $this->load->view('login_view',$data);
}
```

So on a normal page load all this controller does is set the variables and load the view.

The view (up until the point of failure) looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

<!-- Meta -->
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
```

However I'm just getting:

`Message: Undefined variable: page_title`

Any ideas? :s

EDIT:

OK so I just discovered something odd.

I'm viewing the above view as the default controller, so `www.domain.com`. However if I view it by going directly to its URL, in this case: `www.domain.com/access/login/` it works fine. I'm not sure why it would make a difference, but it seems to be the root of the cause. But in both scenarios the same controller is being loaded. So I'm still baffled.

EDIT 2: See my answer below. Basically the wrong controller was loading, a controller that shouldn't have existed anymore was still being referenced by a couple of important functions. Doh.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
function login()
{
    $data['page_title'] = 'Login title';
    $data['page_description'] = 'Login description';
    $data['page_keywords'] = 'login,keywords';
    $data['referer'] = $this->session->flashdata('referer');

    if($this->input->post('email'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_password');
    }
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // Log failed attempt against IP address
            $this->bruteforce->log_fail( $this->input->ip_address() , $this->input->post('email',true) );

          $this->load->view('login_view',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            // Go to accounts home
            if($this->input->post('referer') != '')
            {
                redirect($this->input->post('referer'));
            }
            else
            {
                redirect('dashboard');
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it I'm afraid. Keep in mind the above is exactly how the rest of the app works and it's fine (and I'm pretty sure it was fine a few weeks ago with no changes since), so I suspect it's something more nefarious than that, unless I can't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: try to load your view after $data

Comment: means after you setting $data[] and $this->load->view('login_view',$data); above your if () and check it's working?

Comment: Ah that didn't do it, but I just discovered something new, will update the question.

Comment: Hi there, that would only trigger on form submit. This issue is present on page load. RE: Running the email==false check before validation… it does already.

Comment: Incidentally I've completely removed the validation code, and left only the variable definitions and the view load, the problem is still present, so don't get distracted by those statements, they aren't the issue.

Comment: As I said, you're getting distracted by the wrong things :) I worked out the issue, will add an answer!

Answer (score 0):

OK so I'm not 100% sure of what was going on still, but I found the root cause of the issue.

My `default_controller` in my `routes.php` file was set to `'login'`, and not `'access/login'`. Equally my `index()` function on my access controller was forwarding to `'login'`, not `'access/login'`. What really puzzles me is why the page was loading at all. As technically `'login'` on its own should surely be generating a 404 (and if not, then why wouldn't the variables be available). So still a bit confused, but at least the issue is resolved. Why this has only cropped up now, I'm also still confused.

EDIT: I'm an idiot. I had a 'login' controller left over from earlier in the project. So still not sure why this problem didn't crop-up before, but I at least know why the variables weren't working, because a completely different controller was loading! Sorry for wasting anyones time.